# SQL SYNTAX "WHERE" CONDITION NOTATION "(0,1)"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm now learning about Pivoting in SQL, and one of the examples is:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB($$
  SELECT
    meal_id,
    DATE_TRUNC('month', order_date) :: DATE AS delivr_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) :: INT AS orders
  FROM orders
  WHERE meal_id IN (0, 1)
    AND order_date < '2018-08-01'
  GROUP BY meal_id, delivr_month
  ORDER BY meal_id, delivr_month $$)
  AS ct (meal_id INT,
         "2018-06-01" INT,
         "2018-07-01" INT)
ORDER BY meal_id ASC;
```

Can you tell me what does `WHERE meal_id IN (0, 1)` mean? I've tried to search for the answer but can't find any good explanation.

If you could help me, I'll really appreciate it. Thank you...

Comment: it is the same as `meal_id =0 or meal_id=1`

Comment: See samples [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/)

Comment: omg im so stupid :'(. thx @Jens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Within the brackets, you can specify elements that would otherwise be individually checked by `meal_id = 0` and connected by `OR`-Operator